# Display different values for a variable in different conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
var fontSize = $('.basic_unit').css('font-size');
var DocHeight = 11000;
if(fontSize == 6){
    docHeight = 32000;
}else if(fontSize == 8){
    docHeight = 48000;
}
var variableXXX = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
 
    var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / DocHeight;
 
     if ( scrollPercent >= 5 && variableXXX == false){
        variableXXX = true;
          alert($(document).scrollTop()); 
      }
});
var variableXX = false;
$(window).scroll(function() {
 
    var scrollPercent = 100 * $(window).scrollTop() / DocHeight;
 
     if ( scrollPercent >= 5 && variableXX == false){
        variableXX = true;
         $(".onscroll5").fadeIn(0); 
      }
   else if ( scrollPercent < 5 && variableXX == true){
         variableXX = false;
         $(".onscroll5").fadeIn(0); 
     }
});
```

```css
body{ margin:0; padding:0;}
#header{width:100%; border-bottom:red 1px solid; position:fixed; height:30px;z-index:1000;  margin-top:0;}
#wraper{width:100%;  padding-top:30px; text-align:center; }
.basic_unit{width:800px; height:1300px; border:rgba(0,0,0,1.00) solid 1px; margin:auto;}

.basic2{width:200px; height:200px; background:red; display:none;}
.fixed {position:fixed;}
.center_center{ display:inline-block;z-index:100;}
#container{overflow:hidden; background:rgba(255,0,234,0.20); display:inline-block; }
.left { margin-left:0;  }
.right { right:0;  }
.left_total {left:0;}
.right_total {right:0;}
.center { left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, 0); }
.top { top:30px;; }
.bottom { bottom:0; }
.middle { top:50%; transform:translate(0, -50%); }
.center.middle { transform:translate(-50%, -50%); }
#right_wraper{ float:right; border: 1px black solid; width:300px; text-align:right;}
.intime{width:200px; height:200px; background:blue; display:none;}
.inscroll{width:20px; height:20px; background:yellow; display:none;}
.triggers{ background:rgba(0,255,252,1.00); width:40px; height:40px;}
@media  (max-width: 700px) {
    .basic_unit {
  font-size:2px;
    }
}
@media (min-width:701px) and (max-width : 1200px) {
    .basic_unit {
  font-size:6px;
    }
}
@media (min-width : 1201px) {
    .basic_unit {
  font-size:8px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="wraper">
<div id="container">
<div id="right_wraper">
<!--IN SCROLL--> 
<div class="inscroll fontbig1 onscroll5 fixed middle outtime2 "></div>
</div>


<!--IN SCROLL--> 
<div class="inscroll fontmedium3 onscroll10 fixed bottom center outscroll25 right_left" style="border: solid black 50px"></div>

<!--TRIGGERS--> 
<div class="triggers fixed top left_total">
</div>
<div class="triggers fixed bottom left_total">
</div>
<div class="triggers fixed top right_total">
</div>
<div class="triggers fixed bottom right_total">
</div>
<div class="basic_unit">
A <p style="font-size:6px;">A</p><p style="font-size:8px;">A</p><p style="font-size:2px;">A</p>
</div>

<div class="basic_unit">

</div>
<div class="basic_unit">
</div>
<div class="basic_unit">
</div>
<div class="basic_unit">
</div>
<div class="basic_unit">
</div>


</div>
</div>
```

I need to display a different value for the variable `DocHeight` in the 3 following cases:

- When font size in class `basic_unit` is `2px`, `DocHeight=11000px;`
- When font size in class `basic_unit` is `6px`, `DocHeight=32500px;`
- When font size in class `basic_unit` is `8px`, `DocHeight=38500px;`

```js
if ($(".basic_unit").css("fontSize", 2)){ var DocHeight= 11000;};
if ($(".basic_unit").css("fontSize", 6)){ var DocHeight= 32500;};
if ($(".basic_unit").css("fontSize", 8)){ var DocHeight= 48500;};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your `if` contidions are always true, all of them, as setting a `css()` value returns the wrapped element, which is always truthy

Answer (score 1):

```
var DocHeight;

switch ($(".basic_unit").css("fontSize")) {
    case '2px' :
        DocHeight = 11000;
        break;

    case '6px' :
        DocHeight = 32500;
        break;

    case '8px' :
        DocHeight = 48500;
        break;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work @user1636505, it looks like my browser doesn't read the font size of basic_unit class

Comment: @IvanSoler how you check it? You can log to the browser console by console.log($(".basic_unit").css("fontSize")).

Comment: how would it modify the code? @user1636505

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the CSS, rather than checking if it's matched a value. What you want to be doing is checking if the value if the CSS property matches one of your desired values.

```
var DocHeight;
switch($(".basic_unit").css("fontSize")){
  case "2px": 
    DocHeight = 11000;
    break;
  case "6px": 
    DocHeight = 32500;
    break;
  case "8px": 
    DocHeight = 48500;
    break;
}
```

This will get the get the font size `$(".basic_unit").css("fontSize")` and compare it to each value in the statement, setting the `DocHeight` if it's found.

Note: I'm assuming you're using px, but you can adapt this for `em` or other possible units.

Comment: Thanks for answering @DBS I made an edit with all the code because it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, did you read jquery docs about `.css()` fucntion?

When you execute:

```
if ($(".basic_unit").css("fontSize", 2)){ var DocHeight= 11000;};
if ($(".basic_unit").css("fontSize", 6)){ var DocHeight= 32500;};
if ($(".basic_unit").css("fontSize", 8)){ var DocHeight= 48500;};
```

DocHeight will taken from end if, because `.css(property, value)` set value, not get.

I think you need to ckeck value?

```
var fontSize = $('.basic_unit').css('font-size');
var docHeight = 11000;
if(fontSize == '6px'){
    docHeight = 32000;
}else if(fontSize == '8px'){
    docHeight = 48000;
}
```

Comment: Hi @veniamin your answer is right but it seems not to work in my code, could you tell me how to set the condition for 2px font size value?

Comment: Simply add if condition for 2px size

Comment: it still doesn't work could you check the code in css that changes font-size if  window width changes? Maybe the mistake is there.